# SQL foreign key restraint referencing information_schema

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, information-schema

Is it possible to "constrain" columns in one table which "reference" columns from views in `information_schema` in any way (it needn't be a proper foreign key constraint, hence the scare quotes)?-- I need a minimally-intrusive way of adding arbitrary metadata about existing column data (e.g. to add "comments" about e.g. the value `shop.cheeses.name` for `shop.cheeses.id =`*n*), and so I thought of defining an extra table as such:

```
CREATE TABLE shop.metadata (
    `table_schema` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    `table_name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    `column_name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    `record_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `comments` TEXT NOT NULL, /* just to show the purpose of the table */
    PRIMARY KEY (`table_schema`, `table_name`, `column_name`, `record_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`table_schema`, `table_name`, `column_name`) REFERENCES information_schema.TABLES(`TABLE_SCHEMA`, `TABLE_NAME`, `COLUMN_NAME`)
);
```

However, this statement returns `ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint`, presumably because `TABLE_SCHEMA`, `TABLE_NAME` and `COLUMN_NAME` are not defined as `UNIQUE` (**EDIT:** Even if the columns were unique, it seems it wouldn't be possible because you can't reference views in foreign key constraints).

Still, is there no other way to define a requirement that

- `shop.metadata.table_schema` must contain an extant value from `information_schema.TABLES.TABLE_SCHEMA`
- `shop.metadata.table_name` must contain an extant value from `information_schema.TABLES.TABLE_NAME`
- `shop.metadata.column_name`must contain an extant value from `information_schema.TABLES.COLUMN_NAME`
- Any quadruple of `(TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, record_id)` is unique?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` *tables*, are in fact views, so you cannot reference them. You would need to maintain your own table with the correct unique constraints, and possibly populate it with a scheduled job, then reference that.

Comment: Just use a before insert/update trigger and you can maintain your own constraint.